# Providing context to user index results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app I have an index of users that I filter using checkboxes. I'd like to provide some context to the results of the filtering. Say if I check hometown, I'd like to provide some dialog that says "20 people are from your hometown" or something. Is there a way to do this that is pretty easy to grasp?

I know enough to return the number of users each search renders with `<%= @users.count %>`, but how can I add the context depending on the search parameters?

Here's an example of my code:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, :url => search_users_path, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
  <table id="careerCriteria">
    <tr>
      <td class="head">Hometown:</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="normal"><%= current_user.profile.hometown %></td>
      <td class="check"><%= f.check_box :profile_hometown_cont, {}, "#{current_user.profile.high_school}", '' %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<div class="userSnapshot">
...
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check the [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem. It's great for simple filter needs. If you need something more complex, you'll probably want to roll your own objects.

Create an ActiveModel compliant class and use `form_for`.

For example, put something like this in `app/models/user_filter.rb`:

```
class UserFilter
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attr_accessor :hometown, :user

  def initialize(user, attributes = nil)
    @user = user
    if attributes
      attributes.each do |name, value|
        send "#{name}=", value
      end
    end
  end

  def count
    @count ||= users.count
  end

  def users
    if hometown?
      User.where(:hometown => user.hometown)
    else
      User.scoped
    end
  end

  def hometown?
    hometown == "1"
  end

  def message
    if hometown?
      "There are #{count} users from your home town"
    else
      "There are #{count} users"
    end
  end

end
```

Now, you can use the `UserFilter` for your index action, instead of the `User`-class:

```
def index
  @user_filter = UserFilter.new(current_user, params[:user_filter])
end
```

And in your view (simplified):

```
<%= form_for @user_filter, :path => users_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :hometown %>
<% end %>

<%= @user_filter.message %>

<% @user_filter.users.each do |user| %>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

I would start with something like this, but would quickly create some other classes to cure the repetitive check in messages and stuff.

ActiveModel is a bit hard to get used to at first, so play around a bit and read the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel.html) well.

I hope this gives you some ideas how to move forward.